How to add "make" command to simulated linux system on QUME
I'm working on a project: Use QEMU to simulate the embedded ARM development board and embed a LINUX system on it.
It is now possible to start the simulated development board and run the LINUX kernel.
But now some commands are missing, such as make and insmod.
How can I import these commands to my emulated SD card?
In my embedded ARM development board, the output of uname -a is the following:
Linux (none) 5.10.229 #1 SMP Tue Nov 12 08:23:49 CST 2024 armv7l GNU/Linux

This system is 32-bit. Do you have any good methods?
